# RMagick: Must specify image size (in Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, imagemagick, rmagick

I managed to run this line in development with no problem:

```
canvas = Magick::Image.read("caption:#{something}")
```

But deploying in Heroku, this message appears:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError (must specify image size `something?' @ error/caption.c/ReadCAPTIONImage/135)
```

Is there any way to proceed without providing image dimensions? I need to these image files with text on the fly and I can't provide an exact width.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely having a compatibility issue between rMagick and ImageMagick (which rMagick uses). I had the reverse problem: reading images suddenly didn't work locally, but worked fine on production.

I just read that Heroku is using a very old version of ImageMagick (6.5, but that may have changed.)  I would try downgrading the version of rMagick you are using by setting it in your Gemfile. I'm using v 2.13.3.

`gem "rmagick", "2.13.3", :require => "RMagick"`

Comment: If you are setting up ImageMagick yourself on your on unix build I found that these versions resulted in resolving the error above.

rmagick (2.13.2)
ImageMagick 6.7.7-10